# Copying image raw data

Tags: c, image

I get a pointer to a raw image data from a thread every time a change happens and I want to make a copy of it before another thread uses it. How can I achieve this if I don't know the size of raw data, since it randomly selects a size and gives the raw data?  How can I copy the raw data from this pointer?

Comment: If you don't know how much data is being pointed to and there is no EOT marker, you cannot do this reliably.

Comment: A pointer to raw data does not tell *anything* about its size. Therefore, the solution is simple: you must add a mechanism to forward the size as well... For example, expanding the "raw data" size by one int and writing the size in this.

Comment: then how do i do it? If  I can calculate the width and height of the dumped image, which is the reliable way to make a copy of this pointer

Comment: If you know the total number of bytes (which I assume you can calculate from width * height * Bpp) then you can do a simple `malloc` and `memcpy`.

Comment: Do you have to copy it? Usually, such large buffers are signaled to other threads by queueing the address and the pointer immediately reseated by malloc or by popping a buffer or index from a free pool.  The memcpy is redundant and wasteful.

Comment: yes i have to make a copy of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a copy of your raw pointer "data", you need additional information: the size of this data. The raw data points to an image, and so you already have `width` and `height` at time of creation; you may also have a `bpp` (bytes per pixel) if this is not an 8-bit/pixel image. Multiplying these three will give you the raw data size.

Currently, you are only forwarding the address of the raw data. To have access to the other variables, you need to forward the rest as well.

One option (per my comment) is to expand the `malloc`ed raw data size by the size needed to store `width` and `height` (and optionally, `bpp`) and store these at the very start.

A better way (because more manageable) would be to create a `struct`:

```
struct myData_t {
   int width;
   int height;
   void *data;
} myData, *myDataPtr;
```

Fill this struct with your data and return its *address* to your other function(s).

Remember to do a memory clean up in the correct order: first, free `myDataPtr->data`, and only then free `myDataPtr` itself.